# css specificity and colour

Tags: css, colors

Please may someone explain why the text 'impact on market' is green as opposed to yellow?
I was expecting this to be yellow

---

**HTML**

```
<div> 
   <h4> International news </h4>
   <article>
      <h4 class= "headline"> news develop</h4>
      <aside>
         <h4> impact on market </h4>
      </aside>    
   </article>
</div>
```

---

**CSS**

```
h4 {
   color:blue;
}

.headline {
   color:red;
}

article {
   color:black;
   font-style:normal;
}

aside h4 {
   font-style: italic !important;
   color yellow;
}

article h4 {
   font-style:normal;
   color: green;
}
```

Comment: Please include your actual CSS. This is not valid CSS.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `article h4` comes after `aside h4` and their degree of specificity are equal. CSS files are processed from top to bottom and if another style comes along with an equal or greater specificity, then that will override the previous style.

You can use this:

```
side > h4 {
   font-style: italic !important;
   color yellow;
}


article > h4 {
   font-style:normal;
   color: green;
}
```

Where `>` means only affect direct descendants. This is typically better to use than `!important`, since `!important` is considered the very last resort.

Further reading on CSS specificity:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity
http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Further reading on `!important`:
http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Answer (score 1):

The order in which you put them.  The last one is the one written last, so therefore more important.

Try:

```
article aside h4 
{
font-style: italic !important;
color: yellow;
}
```

Specify the structure more.

Alternative, create a class.

```
<h4 class="level3"> impact on market </h4>
```

Then add

```
.level3
{
 color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is all about CSS weights, here

```
article h4
```

is overriding

```
aside h4
```

you can change order or edit the

```
aside h4
```

for

```
article aside h4
```

and it will work. Both will work, change order or edit the selector.